# Ajax query and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

Im using rails 3.1, and I am creating a search form with ajax, I have already the form working with a post method, I am missing something here...
So in my view I have

```
<%= form_tag(root_path, :method => "post",:id =>"formid") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "El que quiero") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :quiero, nil, :class => 'drug_autocomplete' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :number1 %>

  <%= label_tag(:number1, "El modelo que tengo") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :tengo, nil, :class => 'drug_autocomplete' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :number2 %>

  <%= label_tag(:size1, "Talla de el que tengo") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :size1%>

  <%= submit_tag("Do it!") %>

<% end %>
```

Ok and I wrote in the application.js something to handle the submit event.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form_id").submitWithAjax();
})
```

The controller recibes the parameters in the form, and create a query to the database like this.

```
@itemsok = Contribution.where("first_item_id = ?",item1.id).where("second_item_id = ?",item2.id).where("second_item_grade = ?",size1
```

And then returns the parameters found in the db in the same view

```
<%if not @itemsok.nil? 
  @itemsok.each do |searches|
%>
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="width:100px;"><%= searches.first_item.description %>  </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:30px;"><%= searches.first_item_grade %>  </td>


  <td style="width:150px;"><%= searches.second_item.description %> </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:30px;"><%= searches.second_item_grade %>  </td>
  <td style="width:150px; font-size:18px;"><a href="<%= contribution_path(searches.id) %>">Show</a>  </td>


</tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is the same creating a query to the database but with ajax so no reload  in the page is needed.
First question, I have to handle the data from the form somewhere in the javascript, where?
Second question, how do I handle the data when is back

I am totally lost in Ajax with Rails, so any help/hint would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my terrible english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function to submitWithAjax is calling serialize() which prepares the form data for you.

Your controller for the form action will need to respond to format.js ABOVE format.html and you will need a file matching the action name in the appropriate view folder with the ".js.erb" extension.

Within that ".js.erb" file you can call arbitrary jQuery to replace content, change elements of the page, or trigger actions.

```
$('#lightBoxClose').trigger('click');
$('#flashContentContainer').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "shared/flash_bar") %></div>');
```

One other thing is to make sure your application responds with the format.js action you can change your submitWithAjax function like so:

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action + '.js', $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};
```

Notice the '.js'.

If you haven't seen it check out [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to handle this with Rails native ajax utilities. In other words, your form tag should look like this (notice the `remote` param):

```
form_tag(root_path, :method => "post",:id =>"formid", :remote => true)
```

This is all you need to post via ajax. But then you need to handle the response. In your javascript file, do this:

```
$('#formid')
    .bind('ajax:success', function(response) {
      // response is what gets sent from the controller
      // so send only the dynamic data and insert it into the DOM
    }
```

See the Rails 3.1 documentation for other ajax callbacks like `ajax:complete` and `ajax:error` and so on.